# Segmentation Fault C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" run-time error with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
#include "SortedList.h"

using namespace std;

#define BOUNDS 100

int main() {

    SortedList *list = new SortedList();  // points to the sorted list object
    Student *create[BOUNDS];  // array to hold 100 student objects
    int num = 100000;   // holds different ID numbers

    // fills an array with 100 students of various ID numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++) {
        create[i] = new Student(num);
        num += 10;
    }

    // insert all students into the sorted list
    for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++)
    list->insert(create[i]);

    // individually deletes each student
    num = 100000;
    for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++) {
        delete list->find(num);
    num += 10;
    }

    // insert all students into the sorted list
    for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++)
    list->insert(create[i]);

    num = 100000;
    for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++) {
    list->remove(num);
    num += 10;
    }

    cout << "test2" << endl;
    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

I have narrowed the error down to the `delete list;` lines (or whichever one comes first). I am just wondering as to why this is and how to possibly fix it. Any insight on this matter would be useful.

Comment: You seem to be running this on a unixoid system. So use Valgrind ;)

Comment: "// fills an array with 100 students of various ID numbers"  That loop does not do what this comment says.

Comment: For reference, every time someone types `using namespace std;`, i kick a puppy.  Think about the poor puppies before you do it again.

Comment: @cHao what did the puppies ever do for me?

Comment: Nothing wrong with `using namespace std` unless it's in a header file.

Comment: @cHao i'm new to c++, just wondering why I shouldn't type it?

Comment: @Karl: That one yelped pretty loud.  Hope you're happy with yourself.

Comment: @Pat: Because it does exactly what it's meant to -- it takes everything it knows about from `std`, and sticks it into your namespace.  Including stuff with very basic names you probably didn't expect; for example, there's a `std::left` and a `std::right` (I/O manipulators); a `std::find` and `std::sort` (algorithms)....and of course, all the C functions that have been declared.  Basically, you turn your namespace into a bit of a minefield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems that I can see.

First, in this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++) {
    x = new Student(num);
    num += 10;
}
```

You are creating a bunch of dynamic `Student`s and putting the latest one in `x` and the previous one is lost. This creates 100 `Student`s dynamically and 99 of them are leaked. Also it doesn't fill an array with `Student`s like the comment above it says it does. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here so I can't comment on what you need to do instead.

Secondly, you are calling `delete` here:

```
delete list->find(num);
```

on `Student`s that are in automatic storage (the stack) (because you filled the list with pointers to the `Student`s in `create` which holds automatic `Student`s), which leads to undefined behaviour and is probably the cause of your segfault. You don't need to deallocate these `Student`s because they will be deallocated when the array goes out of scope at the end of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely leaking memory:

```
// fills an array with 100 students of various ID numbers
for (int i = 0; i < BOUNDS; i++) {
    x = new Student(num);
    num += 10;
}
```

The `x` is leaked in this snippet, unless the ctor of `Student` somehow magically inserts itself somewhere, where the pointer can be tracked.

And that might or might be related to the crash.

Comment: `num` is not used as an index to any array so it does not matter that `num / 10 > NBOUND`. Also, the `delete` is not "deleting uninitialised objects" but `delete`ing objects that are not dynamically allocated, which yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, you still have two erroneous comments: `// ERROR: 'create' not initialized` (the objects in an array are initialised if they are not built-in types) and `ERROR: deleting uninitialized objects (may not be 0)` which is wrong because of what I said above.

Comment: What C++ compiler are you using, please? This is simply not true. There is at no point code that initialized the contents of `create` and stack variables do *not* get automatically initialized as you seem to insist. I'd like to know to what C++ standard you are referring to, because this is the first time I hear of this ...

Comment: Yeah, they are. You can see an example here: http://ideone.com/0cu2w . It's the same as if you created a variable on the stack; each element of the array is initialised (if it's not a POD type)

Comment: @Seth: gotcha. Apologies. Forgot that `Student` was a class :-)

Comment: No problem, I do stuff like that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how `StudentList` is implemented, this is kind of shot in the dark but...

`list->insert(&create[i]);` is adding a *stack allocated* object to the list, and then `delete list->find(num);` tries to delete this *stack allocated* object. You can't `delete` stack allocated objects.

In addition to this, your first `for` loop is leaking memory.

And I've been ninja'd.

Answer (score 0):

This line has a problem:

```
list->insert(&create[i]);
```

At that point, `create` has been allocated, but nothing has been put into it.  Probably the result of `x = new Student(num)` should be assigned there.

Answer (score 0):

"create" array is allocated on stack. You are trying to delete stack allocated memory that's why you getting this error.

delete list->find(num);